# Matched and Identical Concepts of Transistors

Tags: mosfet, bjt

[image]

I realize some expressions like "Q1 and Q2 are matched" or "M1 and M2 are identical" about BJT and MOSFET configurations. I have some questions related to this. Are "matched" and "identical" concepts' meanings same? Which parameters of transistors that i mentioned above are same if transistors are identical? Thank you.

Comment: To be "identical" all of the parameters you mention (and more) would need to match (exactly). This cannot happen in the real world.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as an identical transistor. Variations in manufacture dictate that each and every one is slightly different. Identical is a mathematical 'ideal' used for math purposes only.

Matched means the transistors were selected from a pile by measuring them to find the two that "match" closest for a particular variable, presumably the one you care about. However, you can never achieve identical in all parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Identical transistors are very easy to find....... in your SPICE simulator. This can sometimes be misleading, when your circuit has superb performance, because everything matches perfectly, distortions cancel, etc.

If you pick two transistors from the bag, they will have different characteristics (Vbe, hFe, capacitances, Vgs, RdsON, etc).

Also, your transistors will be at different temperatures. Vbe changes 2mV/°C for bipolars, hFe changes too, and FETs are also temperature-dependent.

This will create offset, distortion, and drift in your current mirror.

If you want a better current mirror (or differential pair), you can:

- Add degeneration resistors, to swamp differences in Vbe.
- Use matched transistors, like [DMMT3904](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/115/ds30311-19227.pdf) which have matching guarantees, and they are in the same package, ensuring close (but not identical) temperature, at least if dissipation isn't too imbalanced. These are two independent transistor chips, so they are isolated.
- Use dual monolithic transistors, which are made on the same chip, therefore much better matched, also better temperature tracking, and very expensive.
- Or, in an IC, you can have excellent matching, because transistors are made next to each other on the wafer, in the same fab run, same process, etc, so they will have very close characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

Your circuit shows transistors operated with DIFFERENT VCEs. Thus the currents will be different[EarlyEffect], and the heat dissipation will be different[Ic*Vce], thus the Vbe will be different[~2mv/degree Cent], causing ~ 5% Ic mismatch.

Check out current-mirror topologies that use stacked transistors, so the Vce (and the heating) are identical.